# Not combining values in deposit command, using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm adding a deposit command but when I try to add the `amount` into the `bankBalance`, it doesn't add them correctly into integers, this may sound confusing, I'll give you an example.

Example:

Command: `~deposit 100`,
User balance: Wallet: 120, Bank: 0,
Output user balance: Wallet: 20, Bank: 0100

I wish this explains it, anyways here is my code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Database = require('@replit/database');
const db = new Database();

module.exports = {
    name: 'deposit',
    aliases: ['dep'],
    category: 'Economy',
    description: 'Deposits all or a amount of balance into the bank.',
    usage: 'deposit',
    userperms: [],
    botperms: [],
    run: async (client, message, args, prefix) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    let walletBalance = await db.get(`wallet_${message.author.id}`)
    let bankBalance = await db.get(`bank_${message.author.id}`)

    if (walletBalance === null) walletBalance = 0
    if (bankBalance === null) bankBalance = 0

    console.log(walletBalance, bankBalance)

    let amount = args[0]

    if (!amount) amount = walletBalance

    if (walletBalance == 0) return message.reply('You don\'t have any money!')

    if (amount) {
      if (isNaN(amount)) {
        if (amount.toLowerCase().includes('all')) amount = walletBalance;
      }
      if (isNaN(amount)) return message.reply('The amount must be a number!')
      if (amount > walletBalance) return message.reply('You don\'t have enough balance in your wallet to do this!')
      if (amount) {
        await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, walletBalance - amount).then(
          await db.set(`bank_${message.author.id}`, bankBalance + amount).then(
            message.reply(`Successfully deposited ${amount.toLocaleString()} into your bank!`)
          )
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I'm using [replit](https://replit.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, either the `bankBalance` or `amount` variable is a string causing them to both be converted into a string then appended to each other. A solution would be to use the `parseInt` function to convert both values to a number.

Example:

```js
await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, parseInt(walletBalance) - parseInt(amount));
await db.set(`bank_${message.author.id}`, parseInt(bankBalance) + parseInt(amount));
```

Full Example:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Database = require('@replit/database');
const db = new Database();

module.exports = {
    name: 'deposit',
    aliases: ['dep'],
    category: 'Economy',
    description: 'Deposits all or a amount of balance into the bank.',
    usage: 'deposit',
    userperms: [],
    botperms: [],
    run: async (client, message, args, prefix) => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;

        // Get balances and ensure they are number values
        let walletBalance = parseInt(await db.get(`wallet_${message.author.id}`))
        let bankBalance = parseInt(await db.get(`bank_${message.author.id}`))

        if (!walletBalance) walletBalance = 0
        if (!bankBalance) bankBalance = 0

        console.log(walletBalance, bankBalance)

        let amount = args[0]

        if (!amount) amount = walletBalance
        amount = parseInt(amount); // Ensure the amount is a number value
        if (walletBalance == 0)
            return message.reply('You don\'t have any money!')

        if (isNaN(amount)) {
            if (amount.toLowerCase().includes('all'))
                amount = walletBalance;
        }
        if (isNaN(amount))
            return message.reply('The amount must be a number!')
        if (amount > walletBalance)
            return message.reply('You don\'t have enough balance in your wallet to do this!')
        if (amount) {
            await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, walletBalance - amount);
            await db.set(`bank_${message.author.id}`, bankBalance + amount);
            message.reply(`Successfully deposited ${amount.toLocaleString()} into your bank!`);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking `if (walletBalance === null)` and `if (bankBalance === null)` doesn't make sense any more as they're either integers or `NaN`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros That's true. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, there is my upvote ;)